# espresso : Idling resource for many situations to wait

Tags: android, ui-testing, android-espresso

I have an activity. It can take many fragments. First, It takes a MyFeed fragment which has a listview. The listview's model is taken from network. And I can click one of the item in the list. When I click one of the item, EndFragment is came up. Endfragment also need a model from network.

**So I need a two Idling Resources.**

This is my test scenario.

1. Waiting until the listview's model has been taken
2. Click the first item in listview.
3. Endfragment came up and do something with EndFragment.

Because I need to wait for network request, I made MyfeedListIdlingResource.

```
private class MyfeedListIdlingResource implements IdlingResource {

    private ResourceCallback mResourceCallback;

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return MyfeedListIdlingResource.class.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isIdleNow() {
        boolean ready = mActivityRule.getActivity().myfeedListReady();
        return ready;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerIdleTransitionCallback(ResourceCallback resourceCallback) {
        mResourceCallback = resourceCallback;
    }
}
```

And this is my test code.(I registered above MyfeedListIdlingResource already)

```
    // step 1. Click first item in the listview. This brings Endfragment
    onData(withValue("POST"))
            .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.fm_listview))
            .atPosition(0)
            .perform(click());

    // step 2. Click a view in EndFragment
    onView(withId(R.id.btnComment)).perform(click());
```

In this test code, step 1 is passed well because I registered MyfeedListIdlingResource. But it fails in step 2 with this error code.

Resource com.naver.android.pholar.StickerCommentTest$MyfeedListIdlingResource  isIdleNow() is returning true, but a message indicating that the resource has transitioned from busy to idle was never sent.

How can i handle this kind of situation?
(If I use Thread.sleep(), then the test code is going well)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need IdlingResource if you are using onData statement. Espresso will load your list and navigate to necessary item itself. So this is why you are receiving this error. Seems you should simple remove your idling resource and it will work well without it.

If you want to use delays based at time in your test it is better not to use Thread.sleep() but use IdlingResource as it is described [here](http://droidtestlab.com/delay.html)

Comment: Thanks for your interest. My list has initialized with footer and header. And It's data is received from network. So If i don't use Thead.slpeep() or Idling Resource until receiving the data from network, espresso fails to find listview item.